How do I connect to IBM Cloud Object Storage API from IBM Code Engine Function?
Could someone please help me figure out how to connect to IBM Cloud Object Storage API from IBM Code Engine Functions?
I'm just starting with GET requests for now, but I eventually want to be able to upload to the storage as well.
I'm able to connect via Postman, both to authorize and to GET Bucket List. I am not able to make the same request from my IBM Code Engine Function. The same happens on a sample node/express app, but that's due to a CORS error.
Here is my Function on Code Engine. I have my authorization token from Postman after using my API Key --
async function main(args) {
  console.log('test');
  const apiUrl = "https://s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/"
  const options = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer <<<<AUTHO TOKEN>>>>',
      'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
          'ibm-service-instance-id': <<<<INSTANCE ID>>>>',
      }
  }
  
  
  let apiResponse;
  try {
      const response = await fetch(apiUrl, options);
      // console.log(response)
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('no bueno')
      }
      
      apiResponse = await response.json();
      //console.log(`Response body: ${JSON.stringify(apiResponse, null, 2)}`);
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('u uh', error);
      return {
            statusCode: 500,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: {
                error: error,
            },
        };
  }
  
  const body = {
    args,
    env: process.env,
    apiData: apiResponse,
  };

  console.log(`Return body: ${JSON.stringify(body, null, 2)}`);

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    },
    body,
  };
}

module.exports.main = main;


And here is what my Postman looks like. No parameters in this call:
Postman setup to receive bucket list
